# Is it a good Approach to add SwiftUI View directly into NavigationPath

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui-navigationlink

I've tried to create a Generic Navigation Manager using new NavigationStack & NavigationPath APIs.
For each SwiftUI View (referring to each Screen), I'm creating a 'NavData' object and storing the view in 'content' property of that object. While pushing the view inside the 'NavigationStack', I'm storing the 'NavData' object inside the NavigationPath.

Code demonstration is given below

Manager Class name: NavRouter.swift

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct NavData: Hashable {
    
    private let uid = UUID().uuidString
    let content: AnyView
    
    
    static func == (lhs: NavData, rhs: NavData) -> Bool {
        lhs.uid == rhs.uid
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(uid)
    }
}

final class NavRouter: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var path = NavigationPath()

    func push(to data: NavData) {
        path.append(data)
    }
    
    func back() {
        path.removeLast()
    }
    
    func backToRoot() {
        path = NavigationPath()
    }

}
```

How to Use the 'NavRouter' class

```
import SwiftUI

// Content View

struct ContentView: View {

    @StateObject private var router = NavRouter()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $router.path) {
            VStack {
                Button("Click Me") {
                    let navData = NavData(content: AnyView(View1()) )
                    router.push(to: navData)
                }
                
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: NavData.self, destination: { data in
                data.content
            })
            .navigationTitle("ENV Object")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
        .environmentObject(router)
    }
        
}


// View 1

struct View1: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var router: NavRouter
    @State private var incrementer = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 30) {
            Text("I'm view 1")
                .font(.title2)
            Button("Click Me 1") {
                let navData = NavData(content: AnyView(View2()) )
                router.push(to: navData)
            }
            
            HStack {
                Button("Add") {
                    incrementer += 1
                }
                .padding(15)
                .background(Color.primary)
                Spacer()
                Text(String(format: "%d", incrementer))
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .padding(15)
                    .background(Color.yellow)
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("View 1")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.automatic)
        
        
    }
}

// View 2

struct View2: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}
```

So my query is:
Is it a good approach to directly store view inside NavigationPath??
Requesting you all to share your thoughts on this.

Comment: I would say No. It's probably better to just deal with "trivial data values" (aka structs, not SwiftUI views) as the items in a navigation path sequence. You use this data then to _create_ a new view which you want to push on the stack. Think of a view being a function of an "item": `view = f(Item)`, where `Item` is just a trivial data type.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, it's not a good idea to have SwiftUI view instances laying around in data containers.

One possible approach to decouple source and destination view in a navigation scenario – given your basic concept – would be to use a *function* which returns a view, instead having a property `content` which returns a view:

```
struct NavData: Hashable {
    
    private let uid = UUID().uuidString
    
    let makeView: (NavData) -> AnyView
    
    
    static func == (lhs: NavData, rhs: NavData) -> Bool {
        lhs.uid == rhs.uid
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(uid)
    }
}
```

You need to set the closure `makeView` of course, when you create instances of `NavData`.

That way, you delay the creation of views to the point when you actually use it in the view hierarchy:

```
   .navigationDestination(
       for: NavData.self, 
       destination: { data in
           data.makeView(data)
    })
```

A valid question, though:

What is the benefit of making the source view completely unaware of the type of the destination view, by using a some kind of factory function which returns `AnyView`. What would be the drawback when the source view actually knows about the concrete type of the destination view, and thus creates it themself using the data from the navigation path?